# Clear text on top of an overlay that covers a background image?

Tags: html, css, background-image, overlay

URL: http://www.universityhub.ph/

It's actually a splash page that is capturing leads for a project I am doing.

But you can look at the source code.

```
  <div style="position: absolute; background: gray none repeat scroll 0% 0%; height: 1000px; width: 100%;">
      <div style="background:url(o-COLLEGE-GRADUATION-facebook.jpg);height:1000px;width:100%;">
    <div style="padding-top:88px;padding-left:67px;">
        <img src="emblemmatic-universityhub.ph-logo-11.png">
        <h1 style="font-size: 72px;">THE NEXT<br> BIG THING IS HERE</h1>
        <h2 style="font-size: 18px;">OH, AND WE’RE LAUNCHING OUR OWN THING THAT’S PRETTY COOL.</h2>

    </div>
    <div>
    <div>Get an electronic mail when it’s ready.
    That’s right — no stamps required.</div>
    <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
 </div>
```

If I make the overlay a lower opacity, the letters and logo become a bit blurred.  Right now the opacity is near 1.0 meaning everything looks clear but the overlay is barely visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would put the image in a `:before` element so that its transparency does not affect the actual contents of the container.

```css
body {
 color:#ffffff;
 font-family: roboto;
}
h1 {font-size: 72px;}
h2 {font-size: 18px;}
.content {padding: 88px 0 0 67px;}
.background {
  position: relative;
  background: gray;
  z-index: 0;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
}
.background:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: url(http://www.universityhub.ph/o-COLLEGE-GRADUATION-facebook.jpg);
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<div class="background" style="">
  <div class="content">
    <img src="http://www.universityhub.ph/emblemmatic-universityhub.ph-logo-11.png">
    <h1>THE NEXT<br> BIG THING IS HERE</h1>
    <h2>OH, AND WE’RE LAUNCHING OUR OWN THING THAT’S PRETTY COOL.</h2>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>Get an electronic mail when it’s ready. That’s right — no stamps required.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It never occurred to me that a pseudo-element's semi-existence would be a benefit, good one.

Comment: @zer00ne it could be done with a normal element that was solely used for the background image. The main idea is the `opacity` to be applied to a specific element and not a container which affects all its contents.

Comment: No sir, you are too humble.I know that a normal element can fulfill the same role, but this is a pseudo on a parent. There's an advantage that'll I'll figure out (besides the one you previously mentioned). I perceived pseudos limitation as a liability until now, thanks.